# Is "these are also hidden features as well" a redundant sentence?

Tags: adverbs, redundancy

> These are also hidden features as well.

Is this redundant? I do this a lot, where I say "also" followed by "as well".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is redundant. Choose your favourite:

> These are also hidden features.
>
> These are hidden features as well.